# Practical Differentiation Question Help

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

So here is [The Question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/14V4l.png) i'm having trouble with. I've worked out that the volume would be equal to $$2x^2h - 100h,$$ but I am kind of unsure on where I can go from here, any help would be well received :)

[image: an image with no alt text]

Comment: Hint: take a derivative and do stuff.

Comment: Not sure I understand the problem or your formula.  What is $h$?  If it is meant to be the height of the box, that height is given numerically.  Also...why should there be a maximum?  Doesn't the volume just grow with $x$?  Is there some other constraint?

Comment: How is the height given numerically, this shows a top down view with the width and length, also outlining the 5cm squares that have been cut out. So the if the height isn't given, I've specified it as h.

Comment: The squares in the corners indicated that you cut those parts out. Now fold this net.

Comment: The height seems to be $5$ cm (by folding). But there is no upper bound on $x$. So the volume can be infinity.

Comment: So would I be correct in saying that the volume is given by: 5(2x-10)(x-10) which I believe comes out to be: 10x^2 - 150x + 500?

Comment: Yes, the volume of the box is $$V(x) = 5(2x - 10)(x - 10) = 10x^2 - 150x + 500$$ where $x > 10$.  As others have indicated, there is no maximum volume.